# send form to a different mail with switch case

Tags: php, switch-statement

i'm try to use this code but doesn't work and i don't know why.

How to fix this problem?

html/php form

```
<input type="hidden" name="department" value="" />
<span>Selecione a especialidade</span>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#all-departments" title="Todas as especialidades">
            ALL DEPARTMENTS
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php
        $especialidades_contactos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT especialidades.id, especialidades.nome, medicos.ancora 
        FROM especialidades, medicos 
        WHERE especialidades.id = medicos.id_esp ORDER BY especialidades.nome ASC");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($especialidades_contactos)) {
        echo '
        <li id="'.$row['id'].'"> // THIS ID IS USED FOR SWITCH CASE
            <a href="#'.$row['ancora'].'" title="'.$row['nome'].'">
                '.$row['nome'].'
            </a>
        </li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

PHP code:

```
    //contact form
    require_once("../phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $result = array();
    $result["isOk"] = true;
    if($_POST["first_name"]!="" && $_POST["last_name"]!="" && $_POST["email"]!="" && preg_match("#^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]) && $_POST["message"]!="")
    {
        $values = array(
            "department" => $_POST["department"],
            "first_name" => $_POST["first_name"],
            "last_name" => $_POST["last_name"],
            "date_of_birth" => $_POST["date_of_birth"],
            "phone_number" => $_POST["phone_number"],
            "social_security_number" => $_POST["social_security_number"],
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "message" => $_POST["message"]
        );
        if((bool)ini_get("magic_quotes_gpc")) 
            $values = array_map("stripslashes", $values);
        $values = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $values);

        $mail=new PHPMailer();

        $mail->CharSet='UTF-8';

        $mail->SetFrom($values["email"], $values["first_name"]);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
        switch ($mail->AddAddress(_to_email);){                        |
        case "22": // case the ID are 22, send to this email           |
            $mail->AddAddress(_to_email)="4@example.eu";   //Can't use method return value in write context in /contact_form.php on line 34                     |
            break;                                                     |
        default:                                                       |
            $mail->AddAddress(_to_email)="1@nexample.eu";              |
            break;                                                     |
        }                                                              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: error log say:Can't use method return value in write context in /contact_form.php on line 34